# Tibrv conflict with wpf? (.net 3.5)

Tags: c#, .net, tibco, tibco-rv

I'm trying to listen to tib rv msg (using 7.5.3) in c# with 2 test examples: one is pure c# console app, the other is c# WPF app. What I found is the console app works fine but the WPF one stop getting msg after a while(it varies, sometime after 50 msg, sometime after 30 etc) Any1 has any clue on this?

console app code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using TIBCO.Rendezvous;

using System.Threading;

namespace testTibcoListener
{
class Program
{
    static int count = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        TIBCO.Rendezvous.Environment.Open();
        TIBCO.Rendezvous.Transport aa = new NetTransport(service, network, daemon);
        Connection cn = new Connection("TEST.>", aa);
        cn.MessageReceived += OnDeleteOrderMessageReceived;
        WaitCallback wc = (o) =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Queue.Default.TimedDispatch(0);  
            }
        };

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(wc);

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
    }

    static private void OnDeleteOrderMessageReceived(object listener, MessageReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        TIBCO.Rendezvous.Message msg = args.Message;
        Console.WriteLine(count);
        count++;
    }
}

public class Connection : IDisposable
{
    private string sendSubject;
    private string inbox;
    private TIBCO.Rendezvous.Transport transport;
    private TIBCO.Rendezvous.Listener listener;

    public Connection(string sendSubject,
                      Transport transport)
    {
        this.sendSubject = sendSubject;
        this.transport = transport;
        this.inbox = this.transport.CreateInbox();
        this.listener = new TIBCO.Rendezvous.Listener(
          TIBCO.Rendezvous.Queue.Default, this.transport, this.sendSubject, null);
    }
    public event TIBCO.Rendezvous.MessageReceivedEventHandler MessageReceived
    {
        add { this.listener.MessageReceived += value; }
        remove { this.listener.MessageReceived -= value; }
    }


    public void Send(TIBCO.Rendezvous.Message msg)
    {
        try
        {
            this.transport.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    #region IDisposable Members
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.listener.Destroy();
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

WPF app code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using TIBCO.Rendezvous;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public int count_;
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        count_ = 0;

        TIBCO.Rendezvous.Environment.Open();
        TIBCO.Rendezvous.NetTransport aa = new NetTransport(service, network, daemon);
        Connection cn = new Connection("TEST.>", aa, this);
        cn.MessageReceived += OnDeleteOrderMessageReceived;
        WaitCallback wc = (o) =>
        {          
            while (true)
            {   
                    Queue.Default.TimedDispatch(0);       //          
            }
        };

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(wc);
    }

    private void OnDeleteOrderMessageReceived(object listener, MessageReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        TIBCO.Rendezvous.Message msg = args.Message;
        int aaa = 1111;

        aaa = msg.FieldCountAsInt;

        this.textBox1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
             new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate
             {

                 int a = 1;// rd.Next(2);             
                 this.count_++;
                 if (a == 1)
                 {
                     this.textBox1.Text = "total count: " + System.Convert.ToString(this.count_) + ",queue: " + System.Convert.ToString(Queue.Default.Count);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     this.textBox1.Text = "11111";
                     a = 1;
                 }
                 return null;
             }), null);


    }

}
public class Connection : IDisposable
{
    private string sendSubject;
    private string inbox;
    private TIBCO.Rendezvous.Transport transport;
    private TIBCO.Rendezvous.Listener listener;
    private WpfApplication2.Window1 myWindow;
    public Connection(string sendSubject,
                      Transport transport,WpfApplication2.Window1 window)
    {
        this.sendSubject = sendSubject;
        this.transport = transport;
        this.inbox = this.transport.CreateInbox();
        this.listener = new TIBCO.Rendezvous.Listener(
          TIBCO.Rendezvous.Queue.Default, this.transport, this.sendSubject, null);
        this.myWindow = window;           
    }
    public event TIBCO.Rendezvous.MessageReceivedEventHandler MessageReceived
    {
        add { this.listener.MessageReceived += value; }
        remove { this.listener.MessageReceived -= value; }
    }


    public void Send(TIBCO.Rendezvous.Message msg)
    {
        try
        {
            this.transport.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    #region IDisposable Members
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.listener.Destroy();
    }
    #endregion 
}
}
```

In WPF code, Queue.Default.TimedDispatch(0); is the place won't dispatch any msg from the queue. It's like there's no msg in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1) Instead of ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem, use BackgroundWorker to ensure a background thread is used and you're not starving the UI thread.

2) If you do end up running your while loop on the UI thread, use a WPF DoEvents loop or just call System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents() to make sure that the message loop gets run.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it's related to WPF threading since I have some debug code to show that Queue.Default.TimedDispatch(0) in the while loop does get called all the time. The problem is it doesn't dispatch any msg (not sure it's because it doesnt get any msg from the queue or can't dispatch though) The wierd thing is this same code works fine for console c# app...

Comment: If you have verified that you are initiating message dispatch and the messages are not getting through, it's very likely to be a threading issue, though I may not have identified the threading issue correctly.